# Can I run a try-catch for a command with exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a situation where a command may have different names in different environments. In these environments it is not possible or not permitted for me to alter the name of the command. Given that I know the possible names of the command across the environments I need to be able to run my maven command across all of them without changing the source code every time it is run on a different system.

Say I have the following in my pom.xml where "command" is either `cmake` or `${env.CMAKE_V_HOME}/cmake`:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>

      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>cmake-generate</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>

          <configuration>
            <executable>command</executable>  <!--Here-->
            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/native</workingDirectory>
            <arguments><argument>${project.basedir}/mylib/</argument></arguments>
            <skip>${skipCMake}</skip>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>

    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

**How can I run the above file given that "command" may be under different *known* names on different systems, without having to change to source code every time it needs to run on a different system?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will be able to achieve the desired logic using a bash script.
Having said that, the situation of having different names on different systems is a bad practice.

Comment: The different names is not something I have control over, but need to work with.